# using MVVM-Light is this the correct way to raise events? and where should the persistence go?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

After looking at MVVM-Light and following some examples I put this simple example together. See below, I show one property I'm wiring up, if I make changes to the textbox the textblock is updated.

My questions are

1) Is the VM is supposed to manage raising events of prop changes? 
Some examples (including the macros from mvvm-light) show RaisePropertyChanged from the model but I did not see how the viewmodel was to subscribe to the notification.

This example here showed the VM raising the event

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mvvm-light-whats-messenger?mz=27249-windowsphone7

shows the viewmodel raising the events.

2) Where would persisting the model to the datastore go? Would that be in the model or the view model?

3) After reading from the store how does the view get notified of the initial values? I suppose the answer to this would largly depend on the answer to 2).

Thank you.

The Model

```
    public string StringOne
    {
        get { return stringOne; }

        set
        {
            if (stringOne == value) return;
            stringOne = value;
           // RaisePropertyChanged("StringOne");
        }
    }
```

The View

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="StringOneLabel" Text="StringOne" Margin="30,125,341,0" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="StringOne"  Text="{Binding StringOne}" Margin="145,125,86,0" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="78" Text="{Binding StringOne}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="145,258,0,0" Name="txtStringOne" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="249" >
    <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding StringOneTextChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtStringOne}" />
        </Custom:EventTrigger>
    </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

The ViewModel

```
    public string StringOne
    {
        get { return SettingsModel.StringOne; }
        set
        {
            var oldValue = SettingsModel.StringOne;
            SettingsModel.StringOne = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StringOne", oldValue, value, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can handle property change notifications in either the Model or the ViewModel. Handling it in the ViewModel is the "mvvm-purist" way, while handling it in the Model is often more convenient, especially for smaller applications.
2. Persisting the Model to the datastore would be the VM's job. The Model is nothing more than a dummy data object.
3. The View gets bound to the ViewModel or Model's properties. When they change, it auto-updates providing that the PropertyChange notification gets called.

   You can either expose the Model's properties to the View from the ViewModel like the example you posted (mvvm-purist approach), or expose the entire Model to the View from the ViewModel (often faster to code. Model handles property change notification). In the 2nd case, you would bind your view to something like `MyViewModel.CurrentModel`, and whenever the ViewModel changes the CurrentModel object, the view would get updated.

You might be interested in [this post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) of mine. It's a very simple MVVM example which shows what each MVVM layer contains.